# Passing strings results in empty strings in C?

Tags: c, string, function, arguments

I'm getting a few strings from a user inside main() and I want to pass those strings as arguments to another function. When I run debug I can see that only the last parameter holds the entered string while the 2 previous ones are empty. When I define the strings as global all works fine, how come?

I also tried printing the strings right after getting them from the user and they are stored OK.

Here is the part of the code:

```
  char temp_destination[20];
    char temp_old_date[6];
    char temp_new_date[6];

    printf("Please enter destination, flight date and new date to update\n");
    printf("Destenation: ");
    scanf("%s",temp_destination);
    printf("Current date: ");
    scanf("%s",temp_old_date);
    printf("New Date: ");
    scanf("%s",temp_new_date);
    update_flight_date(database,temp_destination,temp_old_date,temp_new_date);
```

Comment: Make sure `scanf` doesn't overflow your arrays. Either specify the maximum width in `scanf` (such as `scanf("%19s", temp_destination);`), or better yet: use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Comment: The code, as show, have no problem. Please try to create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) which have the problem, and show that.

Comment: How do you enter dates?

Comment: @n.m. - 010100 for exmaple

Comment: Remember that strings in C always have an extra terminator character.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - so if the size of the string is 6 I can actually fit 5 characters without the null terminator? So it should be length of 7 and not 6 right? also when I enter, the return key is added to string or just a null terminator?

Comment: Yes that's correct. An array of 6 characters can only contain at most a 5-character string. The `scanf` function does not add the newline character.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - OK so this sound like the possible cause because I am running over the string for sure... I'll try to fix and update the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
    char temp_destination[20];
    char temp_old_date[6];
    char temp_new_date[6];
```

The moment, user input would be more than these length, memory would be overwritten by each other. In this case since these are on stack(local) so they are overwriting to them-self(undefined behaviour). In the global variable, there too its happening but it just that your program is working.

So you should really make sure that user input should not be more than what you have defined.